# Dynamic menus based on role users in JSP's

Tags: jsp, servlets, session-state, java-server

I've a web application where before I had only one kind of users(Client user) but now I've working and I added the role administrator to the application, so I need to show the menus based in the role,i.e., when the user logged is an user show a limited number of sub-menus but if the logged user is an admin show the full options of menu. The application's back-end is building with JSP's. What should be the best practices  for do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just display it conditionally depending on the role of the currently logged-in user. You can use the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:if>` tag for this.

E.g., if the menus are static, just provide a boolean getter method on your session object representing the currently logged-in user:

```
<c:if test="${user.admin}">
    Show admin menu items.
</c:if>
```

or if EL 2.2 is supported, so that you don't need another one for each role:

```
<c:if test="${user.hasRole('ADMIN')}">
    Show admin menu items.
</c:if>
```

or if you're using container managed authentication:

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.isUserInRole('ADMIN')}">
    Show admin menu items.
</c:if>
```